# Is there any way let SSRS show the result that NOT included in the last run?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

For example:

I preview the report now at 3:00 pm, I want SSRS to show the result that does not show up when I previewed at 2:00pm(last run), and only those records. Thanks

Comment: Not unless you save the data in a table that was previewed at 2:00pm. Your report runs a query against the current data in the system. It does NOT save a copy of it somewhere when you preview the report. When you preview it sticks the data in memory long enough to generate the report but then it is gone.

Comment: Your underlying SQL will have to store the displayed record identifiers and left-join and exclude those from the subsequent results.

Comment: ok, i see, i think i have to create a table then compare the result each time , also insert the old data into it for the next..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is stored procedure based AND your data is time based you could save the last report run time every time it is called in a table. You could then use that value to determine when to start for the next report run. You may need to take into account the user running the report if more than one person will be running it and store a separate last run time for each user.